# How to use the same TODO state in the next entry in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Here is my use case

Say I have in current line

`* TODO XYZ`

When I hit `M-<Return>` it creates a new line as follows

`* TODO XYZ
*`

Is it possible to have the previous state continue?

`* TODO XYZ
* TODO`

Answer (score 1):

`org-insert-todo-heading-respect-content` does what you want. It is usually bound to `<C-S-return>`.

Comment: This works.  Perhaps you can make your answer more comprehensive by explaining what it does when the current heading has no TODO state.

Comment: Well, there is http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html where the first four items explain the different kinds of returns. Not, sure if I have to add something.